# Form submission in partial views in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a simple mvc application . The code is as follows:

Model .cs:

```
public class CustomModel
{ 
   public IEnumerable<lang> lstlang { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<org> lstOrg { get; set; }
}

public class lang
{
   public int langid { get; set; }
   public string langName { get; set; }
}
public class org 
{
  public int orgId { get ;set;}
  public string orgName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller.cs

```
public Action Index()
{
   // Get data from database and fill the model
   var model = new CustomModel();
   return View(model);
}

public Action Partial()
{
   // Get data from database and fill the model
   var model = new CustomModel();
   return PartialView(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public Action Partial(FormCollection frm, CustomModel model)
{
   // Get data from database and fill the model
   var model = new CustomModel();
   return PartialView(model);
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model CustomModel
@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.lang.FirstOrDefault().id);
<input type="button" id="btn" />
@Html.RenderPartial("Partial", model)
```

Partial.cshtml

```
@model CustomModel
@Html.TextboxFor(x => x.lang.FirstOrDefault().id);
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

The thing is, when I click the submit button in the `Partial.cshtml` page, and examine the model in httppost method in `public Action Partial(FormCollection frm, CustomModel model)`, the model contains `null` for both lists `lstlang` and `lstOrg`, but the `formcollection[0]` will give the selected textbox value.

What am I missing, or is this the right way of using partial views?

Comment: Look at the html your generating (in particular the `name` attribute) - `@Html.textboxfor(x=>x.lang.firstordefault().id);` has no relationship to you model whatsoever. [Refer this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) to understand some basic of model binding to a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `FirstOrDefault()`. If you want to post something back to the front end with collections, you'll need to use indexing.

```
Public class CustomModel
{ 
   public ICollection<lang>  lstlang { get; set; }
   public ICollection<org> lstOrg { get; set; }
}


@HTML.textboxfor(x=>x.lang[0].id);
```